# Do you have a wordpress plugin standard in your agency?

Tags: wordpress

A agency i work for creates a wordpress plugin standardization guide which creates a standardizatin in plugin use, like when i have this requirement then use this plugin. Actually this guide icludes 80 plugins.

Do you think this makes sense or do you always choose your plugins based on the requirements of the project?

Answer (score 2):

Having a list of necessary plugins that are:

1. Well maintained.
2. Have standard code base.
3. Well checked for security.
4. Well supported by the developer.
5. Well received by a large & active community.

is a must for any good agency. So yes, it makes sense to have a list like that. Otherwise you may fall into pitfalls mid-project.

Having said that, it's always a good ideas to evaluate new feature rich & well performed plugins. Besides, when you do this long enough, you'll have your own list anyway. So best is the combination of the two:

1. Having a good list of plugins for different features.
2. Adding new Plugins to & removing old Plugins from the list based on new development & evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

We choose based on project. That being said, we do keep a "library" of plugins (not 80 plugins in length, more like 25ish). These are a few staples, but some plugins' maintenance/upkeep are superior to others so it's good to be flexible and not be married to any.

It definitely makes sense to have an idea of what will help in certain situations, so I don't see this really being a negative thing as long as it is understood there is potentially others out there :)

EDIT: I feel I should also note the agency I work for is very small(6 people). We don't have to maintain standards for that many people, and we have pretty free range on our projects. If there were more than a dozen or so developers, it would be nice to have some kind of standardized solutions so that everyone is familiar with the clients' systems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I quite think the same. That means having an idea about which plugins i can use in certain situations but not beeing "married" to them.